# Cannot link Stack Overflow Account to Careers Account

Tags: support, jobs, user-accounts

I have created my StackOverflow Careers panel, and when I click 'add a stack overflow account with over 200 reputation' the site decides that I have no StackOverflow account at all, although my current one has over 300. I log in to both with the same StackExchange Account with the same email etc so I'm curious as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Careers account wasn't linked properly to your Stack Exchange Account, I fixed it for you.

Comment: Thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

As reported by Stack Exchange's team there's a workaround for this: just go to your careers profile, switch privacy to private and then back to public.
You should now be able to link accounts.