# Cannot link stack overflow careers

Tags: bug, jobs

I have the same problem reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225101/cannot-link-stack-overflow-account-to-careers-account).

Who can help me please?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problems have to be solved by an SE employee with direct access to the systems behind SE or even the database.

It has no use to post a new question for this, since the problem the previous time was fixed by an employee.

You should contact the team by clicking [`Contact Us`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) on the bottom of the page. Refer to the previous post and tell you have the same problem. Be patient though. The follow-up can take some days.